# residuals of plane fitting using svd

Tags: svd

I am fitting a best-fit plane for a set of points(X,Y,Z coordinates) using Singular Value Decomposition. So I use

```
M = [x y z 1]
[u s v] = svd(M)
p = v(:,4)
```

Now I want the residuals of the points. I know I can compute the planar equation to get the residual but I wanted to ask if there is some direct way of getting the residuals from the u,s,v matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Residual is the (4,4) element in the v matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can compute the least squares residuals for the overdetermined least squares problem using the data vector *b* and U<sub>N</sub>, the null space portion of the codomain matrix. The answer is *b*<sup>T</sup>U<sub>N</sub>U<sub>N</sub><sup>T</sup>*b*. The derivation is in an image file blocked from display by stackoverflow and available through email.

Comment: In this case, the equation is of type `Ax=0`. How would you calculate the residual vector for such a matrix?

Comment: The posted solution is for the canonical linear system <b>A</b>x = <i>b</i> where the data vector <i>b</i> /= 0 (is not the zero vector). When <i>b</i> is the zero vector or within the null space of <b>A*</b> there is no least squares solution. Thanks for clarification.